# What's the syntax for single-line pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, syntax, pattern-matching

```
word 0 = "Zero"
word 1 = "One"
word 2 = "Two"
```

How would I condense a pattern-matching function like this one into a single line?

I tried `word 0 = "Zero" word 1 = "One" word 2 = "Two"`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use semicolons:

```
word 0 = "Zero"; word 1 = "One"; word 2 = "Two"
```

Answer (score 40):

It's a strange requirement to write a function in a single line. Anyway, `case` could be helpful there too.

```
word x = case x of {0 -> "Zero"; 1 -> "One"; 2 -> "Two"}
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use something like this:

```
word = (!!) ["Zero", "One", "Two"]
```

I don't know if it'll be slower than pattern matching, though.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility:

```
data Words = Zero | One | Two deriving (Show, Enum)

word = show . (toEnum :: Int -> Words)
```

or, if You want it to work with types other than `Int`,

```
word = show . ((toEnum.fromIntegral) :: Integral a => a->Words)
```